# Running n time django_content_type query

Tags: django, django-admin

Django content type table query hits n time in admin user add page other page working fine. Can any one please assists and help for resolve this issue and let me know why its hitting n time? 
here is query

```
SELECT "django_content_type"."id", "django_content_type"."app_label", "django_content_type"."model" FROM "django_content_type" WHERE "django_content_type"."id" = 94
```

also share screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Import `UserChangeForm` from `django.contrib.auth.forms` and add `form = UserChangeForm` to your `UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)` class.

It adds this line: `user_permissions.queryset = user_permissions.queryset.select_related('content_type')` which replaces all the n queries with one single query.

Depending on your user model, you may need to extend `UserChangeForm` ([see docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-the-built-in-auth-forms)).

Comment: Perfect! I kept playing around with prefetch_related and select_related on different user_permissions and content_type fields on Django Admin to speed up my custom User model's admin page with no luck.  This one line took performance from multiple seconds down to a few ms, plus you let me know what the right select_related should have been!

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears when you are subclussing AbstractUser in your user model.
Shortly: you must change your change form in django admin.
Firslty create your new change form and set model = User, where User is your new user model subclassed from AbstractUser:

```
class AdminChangeForm(forms.UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

Then set form in your user admin to class above:

```
@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'is_active', 'last_login', 'date_joined']
    list_filter = ('last_login', 'date_joined', 'is_active')
    form = AdminChangeForm
```

Full tutorial:
https://testdriven.io/blog/django-custom-user-model/

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem. add this function in your UserAdmin

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
from foo.models import UserModel # your auth model

@admin.register(UserModel)
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == 'user_permissions':
        kwargs['queryset'] = Permission.objects.all().select_related('content_type')
    return super(UserAdmin, self).formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

above code override `Permission` queryset to reduse queries by `select_related` function

Comment: you can use admin.site.register(UserModel, UserAdmin) too